# Find how markov-process stabilises

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I got the following problem:

1/8 of the people that live in city A move to city B every year; the rest stays in city A. 1/16 of the people that live in B move to city A every year.

I translated the problem into the following markov matrix:

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
7/8 & 1/16\\
1/8 & 15/16\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I already found the 2 eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors:

1. $\lambda = 1$, eigenvector: $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$
2. $\lambda = \frac{13}{16}$, eigenvector: $(-1, 1)$

But how do I now calculate what the population of the cities stabilises at?

Comment: It’s pretty clear that the populations are stable when city B’s population is twice that of A. Can you see how that relates to the eigenvalues and eigenvectors that you found?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the equation $A\cdot \vec x=\vec x$ as well.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
7/8 & 1/16\\
1/8 & 15/16\\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \binom{x}{y}=\binom{x}{y}$$

The resulting equations are

$\frac78x+\frac1{16}y=x$

$\frac18x+\frac{15}{16}y=y$

They are $\texttt{linearly dependent}$. Thus you can drop one. But you know that $x+y=1$.

Thus you have a linear equation system with two equations and two variables.